# Interesting confusion assigning an optional protocol method to a variable

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a `UITextField`. I want to check if its `delegate` is set, and if so, check to see if a specific optional method is implemented. If it is implemented, then I need to call it, otherwise perform a fallback action. A common way to do this is:

```swift
let field = // some UITextField instance
if let delegate = field.delegate, delegate.responds(to: #selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:))) {
    if delegate.textField?(field, shouldChangeCharactersIn: someRange, replacementString: someString) == true {
        // do something here
    }
} else {
    // Fallback action
}
```

That is all working. But then I had an urge to try a different approach. Instead of using `responds(to:)` I want to assign the optional delegate method to a variable. I came up with the following which actually works:

**Note:** The following code requires a deployment target of iOS 15.0 to compile. If you set the target to iOS 16.0 then it doesn't compile. Not sure why.

```swift
if let delegate = field.delegate, let should = delegate.textField {
    if should(field, field.selectedRange, title) {
        // do something here
    }
} else {
    // Fallback action
}
```

While this works I'm really confused why it works.

1. The `let should = delegate.textField` part makes no reference to the method's parameters.
2. The `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol has 4 optional methods that start with `textField`. These are:

   - `func textField(UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: NSRange, replacementString: String) -> Bool`
   - `func textField(UITextField, editMenuForCharactersIn: NSRange, suggestedActions: [UIMenuElement]) -> UIMenu?`
   - `func textField(UITextField, willDismissEditMenuWith: UIEditMenuInteractionAnimating)`
   - `func textField(UITextField, willPresentEditMenuWith: UIEditMenuInteractionAnimating)`

So how does this work? How does the compiler know which one I meant? It actually seems to only work with the one that happens to be first.

I can't find any way to do this for the other 3 delegate methods. If I really want to call the `func textField(UITextField, editMenuForCharactersIn: NSRange, suggestedActions: [UIMenuElement]) -> UIMenu?` method I can't see how. The following code will not compile:

```swift
if let delegate = field.delegate, let editMenu = delegate.textField {
    let suggested = [UIMenuElement]()
    if let menu = editMenu(field, field.selectedRange, suggested) {
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[UIMenuElement]' to expected argument type 'String'

on the `if let menu = should(field, field.selectedRange, suggested) {` line. This clearly indicates it is assuming the `func textField(UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn: NSRange, replacementString: String) -> Bool` method.

Is there a syntax (that I'm missing) that allows me to assign the specific protocol method to a variable?

I'm going to stick with the tried and true use of `responds(to:)` for now but I'd love an explanation of what's going on with the attempts to assign the ambiguously named protocol method to a variable and if there is a way to specify the parameters to get the correct assignment.

My searching on SO didn't yield any relevant questions/answers.

My code is in an iOS project with a deployment target of iOS 15.0 and later using Xcode 14.0.1. The Swift compiler setting is set for Swift 5. It seems the code doesn't compile with a deployment target of iOS 16.0. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disambiguate either by strongly typing or spelling out the parameters. Neither of us knows why your code is compiling without disambiguating. It doesn't work for us.

```swift
if
  let shouldChangeCharacters: (_, _, String) -> _ = field.delegate?.textField,
  let editMenu: (_, _, Array) -> _ = field.delegate?.textField,
  let willDismissEditMenu = field.delegate?.textField(_:willDismissEditMenuWith:),
  let willPresentEditMenu = field.delegate?.textField(_:willPresentEditMenuWith:)
{ }
```

Comment: I just added some details about my project to the end of my question. It is odd that you guys get errors with the code I posted and I do not. But this answer at least clarifies how to disambiguate so that is extremely helpful. I find it very interesting that you can use `_` in places that don't contribute to the disambiguation.

Comment: [Type placeholders were introduced in Swift 5.6](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0315-placeholder-types.md).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the actual answer to your question, but I will say that your working code doesn't compile for me if I am targeting iOS 16. I get an error that says:

```
error: ambiguous use of 'textField'
if let delegate = textField.delegate, let should = delegate.textField {

UIKit.UITextFieldDelegate:13:19: note: found this candidate
    optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
UIKit.UITextFieldDelegate:23:19: note: found this candidate
    optional func textField(_ textField: UITextField, editMenuForCharactersIn range: NSRange, suggestedActions: [UIMenuElement]) -> UIMenu?
```

But instead of holding onto the function with your `should` variable, why not unwrap the result as a part of your if statement?

Something like this:

```swift
if let delegate = textField.delegate,
   let should = delegate.textField?(field, shouldChangeCharactersIn: someRange, replacementString: someString) {
    if should {
        // perform some action
    }
} else {
    // perform fallback action
}
```

The resulting logic should be the same.

Comment: I added some info to the end of my question. Not sure why you are getting errors while I do not. I appreciate the alternate solution. I had considered this briefly but thought it would behave differently. But after looking at it more I realize this is the simpler approach. So while this is very helpful it doesn't address the bulk of my question about assigning the protocol method to a variable.